# Adding line break to an *ngIf that's inside an *ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular

If I use an `*ngFor` like this:

```
<ng-container  *ngFor="let row of moreInfoData.errorInformationArray; let i = index"  >
  {{row.ErrorCode}}   <br>
</ng-container>
```

It displays:

Error1 
Error2

But I want to check first to see if `row.ErrorCode` exists.  So I'm trying to use this:

```
<ng-container  *ngFor="let row of moreInfoData.errorInformationArray; let i = index"  >
    <span *ngIf="row.ErrorCode; else noErrorCode">
      {{row.ErrorCode}}   <br>
    </span>

    <ng-template #noErrorCode>N/A</ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

In this case it displays:

Error1Error2

What am I doing wrong in the second case and how can I get line breaks between the two Error Codes like the first case?

Comment: Unable to reproduce

Comment: replace span with div or p, you'll get free line break!

Comment: I think the problem is with an outer css class that I haven't shown in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option you can do it using unordered list:

```
  <ul>
    <ng-container  *ngFor="let row of moreInfoData.errorInformationArray; let i = index"  >
      <li *ngIf="row.ErrorCode; else noErrorCode">
        {{row.ErrorCode}}
      </li>

      <ng-template #noErrorCode>N/A</ng-template>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
```

And in your styles put this to hide the dots:

```
li { list-style-type: none; }
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4xzbvr?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 0):

- Put the line break outside of the span tag. This is not valid html
- Put the #noErrorCode before the span, as it's trying to refer to something not yet defined there.

Comment: Point 2 doesnt make sense. And a simplest solution is to use a div or p tag instead of span